# Create a background service to collect and send positions

Tags: android, service

I work on a service that need to be stared/stopped from a specific time, collect user's locations and send them to an API.

I start my service like so

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, CONSTANTES.START_HOURS); //6
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, CONSTANTES.START_MINUTES); //30
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, CONSTANTES.START_SECOND);


    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmTask.class).setAction("START_SERVICE"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

My Receiver

```
public class AlarmTask extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("STOP_SERVICE")) {
        System.out.println("service : got stop instruction");
        if (isMyServiceRunning(context, ScheduleOffsetService.class)) {
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, ScheduleOffsetService.class));
        }
    } else if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("START_SERVICE")) {
        System.out.println("service : got start instruction");
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(context, ScheduleOffsetService.class)) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, ScheduleOffsetService.class));
        }
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

And my service :

```
public class ScheduleOffsetService extends Service {

private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
private String token;


public ScheduleOffsetService() {
}

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

    Location mLastLocation;
    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("Scheduler location : " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        locations.add(location);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60, 10f, mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60, 10f, mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    }

    PropertyApp app = new PropertyApp(this);
    System.out.println("ScheduleOffset token : " + app.getToken());
    if (app.getToken() != null) {
        token = app.getToken();
    } else {
        stopSelf();
    }

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    System.out.println("Scheduler : created");

    return START_STICKY;
}


private boolean gpsIsEnable() {
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {


    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    onEnd();

    System.out.println("Scheduler : got destroyed");
    super.onDestroy();


}

private void onEnd() {
    if (locations.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(/*URL*/)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    WebServiceInterface webServiceInterface = retrofit.create(WebServiceInterface.class);

    JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
        JsonObject content = new JsonObject();
        content.addProperty("lat", locations.get(i).getLatitude());
        content.addProperty("lng", locations.get(i).getLongitude());

        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c);
        content.addProperty("date", formattedDate);
        object.add(String.valueOf(i), content);
    }

    String data = object.toString();

    Call<ResponseRetrofitIreby> call = webServiceInterface.jetLagService(token, PropertyApp.PARNTER_ID, data);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseRetrofitIreby>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseRetrofitIreby> call, Response<ResponseRetrofitIreby> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("RESPONSE : " + response.body().getTrackingPosition().getErreur());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseRetrofitIreby> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


}
}
```

The thing is : When the user asks to be tracked, the listener of my service is no longer called.
Moreover, if the user kill the application the service seems to restart, and thus empty my list of locations.

Can someone, explain me do to ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this library [location tracker background](https://github.com/safetysystemtechnology/location-tracker-background)

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. But did it solve my problem with the service ?